# How can I calculate percentage using FreeMarker template and format it?

Tags: freemarker

I am using FreeMarker and trying to calculate percentage numbers 
for example: I want to calculate 182.72-2% and format the answer up to 2 decimal.

I have tried:

```
<#assign ans = ((182.72?number-2?number))>
${ans}
```

But I want to calculate the percentage using this. I am relatively new to FreeMarker, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
${(182.72 * 0.98)?string("0.##")}
```

EDIT:
or in your case:

```
<#assign ans = ((182.72 * 0.98)?string("0.##"))>
${ans}
```